# Trying to figure out when a table was dropped?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining how a schema change occurred?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/determining-how-a-schema-change-occurred)

Using SQLServer 2008, I see in my schema a particular table was dropped.  I am trying to figure out when / why etc?  Is there any commands I can run to see when the table was dropped, or anything that could help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: (Of course the question itself is slightly different but the answers there apply to this schema change too)

Comment: Yep. Default trace is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Postfactum you not available to see it

If you want to know this in the future - see all about [DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx)