# How to backup the current code of a stored procedure and its permissions as well?

Tags: sql-server, backup, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I often get requests to alter stored procedures, in both test, development and production environments.

I would like a simple way to save the current code of the stored procedure, before the changes, into a table in my "*tablebackups*" database - which is a database where I save records prior to update or delete them.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
sp_helptext 'sp_myprocedure'
```

the idea of usage is something like this:

```
select * into tablebackups.dbo.my_procedure_20150827_1220
from ss_save_my_procedure 'my_procedure'
```

has someone got a solution for this already developed?

Comment: See my answer here for a way to automatically capture all changes my to the structure of your database http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25052/10832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sys.sql_modules ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx)):

```
select top 10 * from sys.sql_modules as m
inner join sys.procedures as p on m.object_id = p.object_id
where p.name ...
```

It is better to alter them because you won't have to worry about existing permissions. If you drop and create the procedure, you have to set them back.

- DO: if not exists, create empty dummy SP and then alter SP
- Don't do: if exists, drop SP and then create new SP

This query should put you in the right direction with the permissions:

```
select 'Proc' = SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id)+'.'+p.name
    , 'Type' = per.state_desc, 'Permission' = per.permission_name
    , 'Login' = pri.name, 'Type' = pri.type_desc 
    , *
From sys.procedures as p
left join sys.database_permissions as per on p.object_id = per.major_id
left join sys.database_principals as pri on per.grantee_principal_id = pri.principal_id
where ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Rather than saving your procedures in user tables, why don't you just set up a SSDT database project and use version control (TFS, Git, Mercurial, SVN or whatever you find appropriate) to take care of versioning?

SSDT or other tools such as [Red Gate's SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) will help you in keeping track of versions and deploying your changes to your envirnoments.

Comment: +1 for source control. This is a much better answer, since saving the code in `tablebackups` will make your like more difficult. Version/Source control is the way to go - either Opensource or 3rd party tools.

Comment: +1 for source control. I sometimes work in places where they don't use/ or servers can't connect to any source control.

Comment: Be the one to introduce it then! Extra smart points to your pocket :)